# React Navigation 5 Header Options

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, stack-navigator

How Do I set the Header right property on the <Stack.Navigator> ? I tried it with screenOptions but it is not rendering the headerRight Content on the right of header. I could set it on the parent Navigation Component which is rendering this custom component but in there I am not able to access the navigation prop. Could anyone please help me? Thank You

```js
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={options3} name="SellerStackNavigator" 
        component={SellerStackNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

const SellerStack = createStackNavigator();

const SellerStackNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  <SellerStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
          headerRight: () => (
                <View style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    marginRight: 10,
                }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        borderRadius: 20,
                        marginRight: 10,
                        marginTop: 10,
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        elevation: 2,
                        paddingLeft: 10,
                    }}>
                        <Image style={{
                            resizeMode: 'contain',
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            marginRight: 10,
                            tintColor: '#000',
                            width: 15,
                            height: 18,
                        }} source={Images.searchImage}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        })}>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        
  </SellerStack.Navigator>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used more or less your code and is working for me, so if you can make a expo I can check what is really happening https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/headerright
Anyways you can accesss your navigation from anywhere with useNavigation hook

```
function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

You can do access to it

```
<NavigationContainer>
    {(route, navigation) => {

return <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={options3} name="SellerStackNavigator" 
        component={SellerStackNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>}}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: HI Anthony, Thanks but I cannot make use of the useNavigation hook since it is the top most navigator component where the <NavigationContainer is also present.